# Xcode unable to find enum in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, enums, scope

I have an enum in my project called `Theme`. It is in a file called `Theme.swift` in `App > shared`. I then have a SwiftUI view called `ThemeView` in `ThemeSettingsView.swift` located in  `App > Shared > Settings`. However whenever I try to declare a variable as `var theme: Theme` I get an error saying "Cannot find Theme in scope."

Any recommendations on how to fix. Do I have the files located in the wrong areas?

Comment: It sounds like your Theme.swift file is not added to your target

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the Target Membership of your Theme file. Check this
[image]